# Lifecycle methods getting executed twice in react js

Tags: reactjs

I m just trying to see the order of execution of lifecycle methods, but I find Logs in console 2 times. I m wondering if constructor,getDerivedStateFromProps,render methods are executed twice, but componentDidMount is executed only once.

I just created a component, called all life cycle methods with console, I m including this component in App.js .

But I tried executing the same code in online editor https://repl.it/repls/ProbableLinedSpof
Here I m getting the proper output(same code in executed even here)

Someone please help with the fix.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I only see it log render once: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcXBa.png

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshots. Read the FAQ

Comment: Do you have `React.StrictMode` in your code anywhere? That invokes each lifecycle twice: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem. Lifecycle methods will be fired multiple times if the application is running in `StrictMode`. Search for this keyword in your project, you should find a `React.StrictMode` tag. Remove it. This will solve the problem. Credit for this goes to @ericgio in your comments sections.

Answer (score 2):

Removing **React.StrictMode** in **src/index.js** will resolve this issue.